# Django Rest Framework: using ModelViewSet to get a list of instances by their PKs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

DRF provides a *super-useful* class called [Model.views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) to create an API with basic REST actions and mapping Django Model, using few lines of code like these:

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing instances.
    """
    queryset = MyObjects.all()
    serializer_class = MyObjectsSerializer
```

If I get `http://myUrl/{pk}/` I obtain data about MyObjects instance identified by `pk`.

Is there a way to ask the API to return a list of more instances, passing the list of their pk*s* in some way?

Comment: Does it matter if you declare what objects you fetch in the body, or does it need to be done in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

You can do stuff like:

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing instances.
    """
    serializer_class = MyObjectsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        pks = self.request.query_params.get('pks', None)

        if pks is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pks__in=pks)

        return queryset
```